# How to convert varchar into decimal and its sum

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(Amount as decimal(10,2))) as result 
FROM tblserviceinvoice
```

and values of `amount` (which is `varchar`) are:

```
    2.00 
  276,00 
  528.00 
  759.00 
  759.00 
  233.00    
7,956.00 
5,328.00
```

But as I run the said query, only `2569.00` is given as result. How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the commas first, then cast. And use a numeric column (integer, decimal, etc.) next time. Varchar is not the appropriate type to store numbers.

Comment: And cleanse the data:  `276,00`.

Comment: Why are you using varchar for numbers? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: thanks for your answers :). actually ive tried double for that, but my values were not save properly on my database,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the above query is only due to these value (7,956.00 and 5,328.00 ) when casting in implemented on these values the value returned as 7.00 and 5.00 due to which the query gives the result as 2569.00.

Just remove these commas from these numbers and the query will execute properly

SELECT SUM(REPLACE(Amount, ',', '')) as result 
FROM tblserviceinvoice

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the commas from the number strings before converting them to numbers:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(REPLACE(amt_tran,",",""),DECIMAL(9,2))) as result
FROM tblserviceinvoice
```